# Should/can COMMIT/ROLLBACK emit an error when no transaction is active?

Tags: transaction, sql-standard

What does ISO/IEC 9075-1:2023 standard say about COMMIT/ROLLBACK queries? Should (or can) they emit an error/exception when executed outside an active transaction?

I am asking because of https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32652 and because the standard is not public/free - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121248/where-can-i-get-read-sql-standard-sql2011.

Here is how the main DB vendors currently behave:

SQLite - https://dbfiddle.uk/BmwZpE6v - emits an error

MSSQL - https://dbfiddle.uk/IK9y_GEK - emits an error

PostgreSQL - https://dbfiddle.uk/tC9pxsJK - no error

Oracle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410508#53412359 - have no "start transaction"

MySQL - https://dbfiddle.uk/UCxKq6nU - no error

Comment: In your MSSQL example, you have a comment expecting that two `BEGIN TRANSACTION` commands should fail - but this is incorrect: _nested transactions are a thing_.

Comment: I've looked at my copy of the 2011 spec, and Part 2 ("Foundation")'s section **17.7** concerns the `COMMIT` statement, and behaviour is defined in terms of _encompassing transactions_, _atomic execution context_, and _condition area limits_ - so a thorough answer to your question would need to define those terms first, and that then depends on the RDBMS. However, the short answer is "it depends".